# .replace function won't replace numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to change all of the `'%2F'` and `'%2B'` into `'/'` and `'+'` in order to retrieve an URL from `Firebase` for an encoded image, but somehow it shows me an `error of undefined` is not an object (evaluating `'NewText.replace'`)

**Here's the part of the code:**

```
getURL(){
    db.ref('/').once('value', (data) =>{
        let RetrieveData=data.toString();
        var NewText = RetrieveData.photoPath;
        var FinalText = NewText.replace(/%2F/g, "/").replace(/%2B/g, "+"); 
        this.setState({
          urlHolder: FinalText, 
      })
    });
  }
```

Is it because the `.replace` function can't replace numbers? If so, what function should I use then?

Comment: No, this means `RetrieveData` contains undefined. Apart from that, you should use decodeURIComponent for this task.

Comment: Instead of messing around with regular expressions, you could (/should) probably simply use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I am fairly new to JavaScript and React Native and didn't know there is a built in function. Cheers man, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

When you read data from Firebase you get back a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot). To get the JSON value from that, you call `.val()` on that `DataSnapshot`.

So most likely what you're looking for is:

```
let RetrieveData=data.val();
```